# Syntax error on linkerscript.ld

Tags: c, linker, syntax-error, ld

I got a small problem with a part of my linkerscript. It says, that there is a syntax error, but I'm not able to recognize where the ... it should be wrong ...

Maybe you can have a look on it:

```
.init_array     :
{
PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
KEEP (*(.init_array))
KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
}
```

Output of compiler is: `/usr/bin/ld:linkerscript.ld:93: syntax error`

Line 93 is the line "KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY ...."

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing terminating semicolons on lines 93-95 ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker))? It doesn't understand `SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY`, you'll have to remove it. There's a [bug filed about it](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18098)